# How to enumerate over specific number/title in shell

Tags: command-line

I want to call:

```
wget linkftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/srainstant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR03108/SRR03108.sra
wget linkftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/srainstant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR03109/SRR03109.sra

#Continuing... to 29

wget linkftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/srainstant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR03129/SRR03129.sra
```

I've tried `{08:29}`, but can't seem to enumerate over both at the same time.

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop and a variable:

```
for i in {08..29}
do
    wget linkftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/srainstant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR031$i/SRR031$i.sra
done
```

Comment: Yes, that was perfect!